# Cambie mi pagina de local a un servidor

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Lo que pasa es que estaba trabajando en una pagina web local con xampp y ahora la pase a una pagina en un servidor lo que pasa es que ya no puedo insertar datos.
Me sale este mensaje
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y despues me manda al "$.ajax" en esta parte de la programacion:

```
function insertarGrupal() {
    var claveGrupal = document.getElementById('claveGrupal').value;
    var nombreGrupal = document.getElementById('nombreGrupal').value;
    var fechaRegistro = document.getElementById('fechaRegistroGrupal').value;
    var horaRegistro = document.getElementById('horaRegistroGrupal').value;
    var responsableRPEGrupal = document.getElementById('responsableRPEGrupal').value;
    var fechaDelGrupal = document.getElementById('fechaDelGrupal').value;
    var valorGrupal = document.getElementById('valorGrupal').value;

    document.getElementById('claveGrupal').value = "";
    document.getElementById('nombreGrupal').value = "";
    document.getElementById('responsableRPEGrupal').value = "";
    document.getElementById('fechaDelGrupal').value = "";
    document.getElementById('valorGrupal').value = "";

    if (claveGrupal != "" && nombreGrupal != "" &&  fechaRegistro != "" &&  horaRegistro != "" && responsableRPEGrupal != "" && fechaDelGrupal!="" && valorGrupal!="") {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/insertarGrupal.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: { claveGrupal: claveGrupal, nombreGrupal: nombreGrupal ,fechaRegistro : fechaRegistro, horaRegistro: horaRegistro, responsableRPEGrupal: responsableRPEGrupal, fechaDelGrupal: fechaDelGrupal, valorGrupal: valorGrupal}
        })
            .done(function (resultado) {
                $('#informacion').html(resultado);
            });
    }
}
```

Ya verifique los campos del php al java y las tablas ya estan bien, al igual que la conexion si funciona ya que se muestran los datos de las tablas pero les digo no puedo insertar datos, todo esta en orden tienen el mismo codigo que uso en local host y funciona bien no se si tenga que ver con el cambio de servidor o algo asi. ayuda porfavor.

**Edit 1:**

No tiene algo que ver agregar algo llamado JSON no se muy bien que sea pero estoy viendo que lo usan mucho para servidores.

Espero que con esta imagen se vea mas claro:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: lo mas probable es que la ruta url: 'php/insertarGrupal.php', esté mal

Comment: Nop Esta bien escrita la ruta

Comment: Revisa la URL completa a la que haces la petición (pestaña Network del navegador). Lo más probable es que esté `pagina.comphp/insertarGrupal.php` o algo similar

Comment: La cambie pero me sigue apareciendo el mismo error

Comment: Qué sale en la consola? Si consumes esa URL que ves en las peticiones, puedes acceder a ella? "La cambié" no nos dice nada de lo que te sucede

Comment: No tenes un error de cors? apreta f12 en el navegador y fijate si no tenes la peticion bloqueada

Comment: Cors?? como los activo? o a que te refieres

Comment: Lo de la url me refiero que coloque esta :"//intranet/tutorias/php/insertarGrupal.php" pero sigue saliendo el mismo error de la imagen y me manda al mismo lugar

Comment: Mira en la pestaña Network de tu navegador a donde realmente esta haciendo la peticion y con que parametros para saber su la url esta bien

Comment: si lo moviste a un servidor, la url de tu servicio no puede empezar nunca por intranet. a que servidor moviste tu back end? a esa direccion tiene que apuntar tu front end...

Comment: todo el contendio de programacion se paso a esa carpeta de intranet a la cual yo me conecto y puese esa direccion se supone que hay esta todo

Comment: A lo que se refiere @gbianchi es que tu url debe verse así `http://tudominio.com/tutorias/php/insertarGrupal.php` y no así `://intranet/tutorias/php/insertarGrupal.php`

Comment: los errores 404 suelen deberse a que no se encuentra el archivo, así que verifica la ruta.

Comment: lo que se me hace raro es que tengo otra pagina donde tengo en el ajas "php/tablamodificar" y cuando entro a la pagina si se muestra la tabla y esta en la misma carpeta donde esta la de insertarGrupal y se ve la tabla perfectamente

Comment: Ya intente poner `http://tudominio.com/tutorias/php/insertarGrupal.php` e igual me sale el mismo error

Comment: Me acabo de dar cuenta que en mi localhost sale el mismo error pero los datos que registro si se guardan en la tabla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo resolvi en mi codigo tengo esta parte:

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';

$conexion = conexion();

$consulta =$conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO T.FAGENDA(NOMBRE_CITA,CLAVE_UNICA, RPE, FECHA_REGISTRO, HORA_REGISTRO, FECHA_CITA, NUMERO_CITA)VALUES(:numeroCitaIndividual,:claveUnicaIndividual,:RPEIndividual,GETDATE(), GETDATE(), :fechaCitaIndividual, :numeroCita);");

$consulta -> bindParam(':numeroCitaIndividual', $numeroCitaIndividual);
$consulta -> bindParam(':claveUnicaIndividual', $claveUnicaIndividual);
$consulta -> bindParam(':RPEIndividual', $RPEIndividual);
$consulta -> bindParam(':fechaCitaIndividual', $fechaCitaIndividual);
$consulta -> bindParam(':numeroCita', $numeroCita);

$numeroCitaIndividual = $_POST['numeroCitaIndividual'];
$claveUnicaIndividual = $_POST['claveUnicaIndividual'];
$RPEIndividual = $_POST['RPEIndividual'];
$fechaCitaIndividual = $_POST['fechaCitaIndividual'];
$numeroCita = $_POST['numeroCita'];

$consulta->execute();

header("Location: index.html");

$conexion=null;
?>
```

Donde `header("Location: index.html");` es el error simplemente lo quite y se soluciono.

Answer (score 0):

Modifica lo siguiente:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '//php/insertarGrupal.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: { claveGrupal: claveGrupal, nombreGrupal: nombreGrupal ,fechaRegistro : fechaRegistro, horaRegistro: horaRegistro, responsableRPEGrupal: responsableRPEGrupal, fechaDelGrupal: fechaDelGrupal, valorGrupal: valorGrupal}
    })
```